# Can I use a Truncated Poisson Model As Selection Equation

Tags: poisson-regression, tobit-regression

Deas StackExchangers,

I am trying to predict rates of returns to capital earned by american families using the Panel Study of Income Dynamics. Because wealth information is incomplete, and because some families have 0 wealth and don't participate in capital markets at all, I have lots of missing data in the outcome variable (which is rates of returns earned coded as 1.05 if the return earned was 5%, for example).

I am trying to pick the right selection correction strategy. Heckman twostep is an obvious possibility. However, I don't have obvious exclusion restrictions that I find justifiable theoretically.

To go around my lack of exclusion restriction, I considered using a tobit type III model (with a tobit selection equation instead of a probit, following Wooldrige) However, the only continuous variable that I have at hand to perform a tobit regression is my returns variable (which is also the main outcome), modified with the missing values set as zero instead of missing. I would then use the log of this modfified returns variable as my outcome, so that the zeros are set back to missing in the outcome, and the functional form is different in the outcome model. I would use the residuals of a tobit ran on the modified returns variable in an OLS regression with the log modified returns variable as outcome. I am not sure how sound this procedure would be, however, since the outcome variable in the selection model would be basically the same as the outcome variable in the second stage model, differing only by the log form.

There is another potential variable I could use to predict selection with more information than in a binary probit; the number of years respondents have participated in capital markets (have reported non zero wealth). However, this variable is not exactly continuous. It ranges from 0 to 12 and looks more like a count variable in its frequency distribution. I know tobit models are not recommended with such count variables. But would that be acceptable to use it in the tobit selection anyways? (And by this better than using Heckman without exclusion restrictions)

If not, I was wondering if I could use a truncated poisson model as my selection equation, instead of a tobit. If I do so, could I use the residuals from this poisson regression in my final OLS model, as is done in type III tobit correction models, to test/correct for selection bias?

Any thoughts are welcome!

Thanks,

Maude